# Filtering starting from a Foreign key users that are not staff combined with other filters

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='activity',
 sent_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need a query that exclude all users that are not staff and sent is null.

So I tried to use exclude:

```
Post.object.all().exclude(user.is_staff=True)
```

and I get the following error:

```
keyword can't be an expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In queryset's arguments to get access to model attributes you need to use `__` instead of `.` like this:

```
Post.object.all().exclude(user__is_staff=True)
```

To exclude null values you can use [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
Post.object.all().exclude(user__is_staff=True, sent_at__isnull=True)
```